# Error: Cannot create the component ComponentClass as it was not imported into the testing module

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, karma-runner

I have the above test base set up on an Angular Cli 6.0.1 app.

Using Jasmine V2.8.0 and Karma V2.0.0

I'm getting the following error on line 13

`Error: Cannot create the component AddressLookUpDirective as it was not imported into the testing module!`

Can’t figure out what is going wrong.. any suggestions most welcome

```
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing';

import { AddressLookUpDirective } from './address-look-up.directive';

describe('AddressLookUpDirective', () => {

    let component: AddressLookUpDirective;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AddressLookUpDirective>;

    beforeEach(() => {

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [
            AddressLookUpDirective
          ]
        });

       fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AddressLookUpDirective);
       component = fixture.componentInstance;

   });
});
```

Comment: Does the `AddressLookUpDirective` have a `templateUrl` or `styleUrls` property in it's decorator?

Comment: @vincecampanale No but it has a selector `@Directive({
  selector: '[addressLookUp]'
})`

Comment: I was getting a similar error but found out i had not included the `declarations: [ XYZComponent ]` object inside the test bed config.

Answer (score 0):

You shall create a mock component to test Directives and import both directive and mock component into TestBed.

```
@Component({
    template: `<input type="text" hoverfocus>` 
})
class TestHoverFocusComponent {
}
```

@see https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/directives/